# Firebase Android count children/ badge

Tags: android, count, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to develop a simple shopping application. There will be a few product categories and I use different activity with ListView for every category. When User choose product category (say items1 ="drinks")- new screen opens and he can add "soda", "cola"... I want to add count badge on every category to show number of products per category.
So, for example for "items" I need to display 5, for "items1" - 2 and for  "items10/11" - display 1:

[image]

my ActivityItems1 code:

```
       private Firebase mRef;
       private String mUserId;
       private String itemsUrl;
       private TextView badge;


       itemsUrl = Constants.FIREBASE_URL + "/users/" + mUserId + "/items1";



    // Set up LisView
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);  

    // Find badge
         badge =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.badgeView);


    // Use Firebase to populate the list.
    new Firebase(itemsUrl)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String   s) {
                    adapter.add((String)     dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue());


     Log.e(dataSnapshot.getKey(),    dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");

     badge.setText(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");
                }
```

After running the code I received Key and number of his children:
E-KJGG2driQ6HJI8R7eve: 1
E-KJGG3Ua6rmlQYn4IHF: 1

it's always 1 child for every Key because Key=Product ID and child of the Key - it's title. **But I need to count Keys/ Product IDs (products in category "drinks") and not his children**...

Comment: You could use a child added and child changed value instead of a value event type, this way you could simply use the dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()

Comment: @YmmanuelFlores `getChildrenCoun()` only makes sense for a value event. Otherwise you simply get a count of the number of properties, which is unlikely to be what OP wants.

Comment: `badgeView=null` indicates that you haven't initialized `badgeView` and thus it will throw a `NullPointerException` when you call `badgeView.setText()`. You're likely missing a `badgeView = findViewById()` in your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ... Nope...if you set the reference at the parent of items...items1....items10...etc  and use the child_added..in each event he would receive a snapshot for each event..(the key of the first event would be 'items') there he can use the getChildrenCount() that would count the children..(-kj....) and that is what OP wants

Comment: @YmmanuelFlores `child_added` fires at the child level, it will *not* fire for the parent. Try it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen as you suggested i tried it and as I said it worked.... I posted the answer so you can try it to. ;)

Comment: Ah.... now I get it. It's a multi-level hierarchy. I completely overlooked that. Good catch, upvoted.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - you're right, I forgot to initialize badgeView. But after I did this - still my TextView / badgeView is empty...                                        `private TextView badge;
        badge =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.badgeView);`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - and my XML:  `<TextView
        android:id="@+id/badgeView"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_item_count"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        /> `

Comment: Firebase has recently released Cloud Functions. Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42713792/5861618) for more details

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[image: Databse Reference]

With this Database you have two options:

1)Use Child Added

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
//You must remember to remove the listener when you finish using it, also to keep track of changes you can use the ChildChange
myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.e(dataSnapshot.getKey(),dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

2)Use the Value listener

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

//You can use the single or the value.. depending if you want to keep track
thismyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.e(snap.getKey(),snap.getChildrenCount() + "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Here is the output for both cases

[image]

If you need to keep constant tracking is best to use the Child events...because otherwise each time anything changes you will receive the entire json over the network, instead of only the portion of information that was changed

If you need a snapshot only once, you better use the singleValue since this way you will receive all the information at the same time

Comment: This answer was made using the new Firebase 3....if you are still using the legacy version and you cannot migrate...the solution will still work the only thing that changes is the way you get your database reference as established here  https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#fix_your_class_references_numbered

Comment: I'll try and post my comment after. Thank you!

Comment: I tried the 2nd approach and my code looks now like this:  `new Firebase(itemsUrl).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
...
                  badge.setText((int) snap.getChildrenCount() + "");
` and still can't see the count on badge...I feel like I do some stupid syntax mistake - but can't figure it out...

Comment: Ymmanuel, It seems like I didn't explain clear enough my situation. I have **different activities for different items**: one for "items", second for "items1"... ("item"&"item1"= product categories: dairy, drinks...)  And when I tried to implement ChildAdded approach - I received Key and number of his children -**it's always 1 child for every Key in this case because Key=Product ID and child of the Key - it's title**).                                       But I need to count Product IDs (products in category) and not his children.

Comment: In SQL it should be:  Select count (Key/ProductID) from items; select count (Keys) from items1 etc.
 So for "items" in first activity I receive 5, for “items1” – 2.
I’ll very appreciate for any help!

Comment: so items, items1..etc are categories like drinks, dairy, meat??? and the K... nodes are products like  milk, soda, water, wine, etc??? and you want t know how many items are per category?

Comment: yes, suppose items1 = drinks category and in this category user can add list: cola, soda... I need to count these drinks for "drink" category/ "items1". So if the user add cola and soda (in Firebase it's 2 different Keys under "items1") - I need to show in TextView "2"

Comment: sure, couple of minutes

Comment: Thank you so much, It returns what i expected.

Comment: I'm not sure if it were mentioned, but your solution gets the count of everything. If we need to the count of something specific. How does that work? At least in my situation I can't seem to figure out how to get just a single child's count.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about that but It can couse of parsing. Try to

```
badgeView.setText(nums+"");
```

maybe It could help.