# Firebase realtime database:How to get ChildrenCount when using AddChildEventListener?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I want to do is to get the number of the children using `AddChildEventListener` as we can do using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`.

I mean

```
thisRoom.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int numberOfPlayers = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
```

Now I can get thisRoom's children but I'm wondering if there's a way to do the same thing using `AddChildEventListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods in a `ChildEventListener` trigger on the individual child nodes, and don't carry knowledge of the entire result. The only way to get a count of the child nodes in a `ChildEventListener` is to keep your own counter, incrementing it in `onChildAdded`, and decrementing it in `onChildRemoved`. This gives you a running counter: a number that reflects how many children your client-code has already processed.

To get an absolute count of the number of children, use a `ValueEventListener`. Note that attaching both a `ChildEventListener` and a `ValueEventListener` to the same location/query, will only transfer the data once. So there's no penalty to attaching both types of listeners, one for each use-case.

Also see:

- [How to count children in addChildEventListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48713456)
- [Find out if childEventListener on Firebase has completed loading all data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34532739)

Answer (score 0):

In firebase firestore we can call a method `datasnapshot.size();` which returns a Int value, you can try this in firebase realtime. Hope this will help.