# How to Retrieve Count of Child Under Root Node in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

```
prev.child("ViewLikes").child(postId).push().setValue("viewed");
```

How to count the number of childs under the the root(9999999977). 
I'm using Value event listener but still the I can't get the counts.

Inside Value event listener below for loop is used.

```
for(DatanSnapshot a:DatanSnapshot.getChildren())
long count=a.getChildrenCount();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Android count children/ badge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600442/firebase-android-count-children-badge)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606235/android-firebase-get-childrens-count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of childrens within the `9999999977` node, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("ViewLikes").child("9999999977");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        Log.d("TAG", "count= " + count);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The out will be: `count= 7`